# What should be returned from BE to FE when a socket connection is refused?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Socket.io to connect BE and FE, and in each connection, the BE will verify the token sent from FE, and if the authentication fails, the connection will be cut up.

I am wondering, when a connection is cut up because of failed authentication, what should be returned from BE to FE by the software development industry standard?

```
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      // Authentication failed, what should I do here?
      socket.disconnect();
    } else {
      // Authentication passed, do something.
      });
    }
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`next(new Error("message")`](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#Authentication-differences) if your authentication is inside middleware. Socket.io automatically send those errors as special error packets to the client, which means you could listen for the event on the client side, like so:

```js
// Client-side
socket.on("error", data => {
  // Do things with the error, such as
  // displaying it on the screen or something
});
```

If you do this, then your auth has to look like this:

```js
// Server-side
// Here I'm assuming you're using
// socket.io v1.x.x+
io.use((socket, next) => {
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      // Authentication failed, send error packet to client
      next(new Error("Auth failed!"));
    } else {
      // Authentication passed, call next to keep going
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is another link if you need a bit more clarification: https://socket.io/docs/namespaces/#Handling-middleware-error

Answer (score 0):

you can send a message to the client telling that the reason of rejected connection is failed authentication

Comment: Do you mean using `res.send()`?